# Asignación dinámica de matriz de clase con destructor protegido

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

> Encontré la pregunta *[Dynamic allocation of class array with protected destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41779374/5290909)* y me pareció sumamente interesante. Quería repreguntarla aquí para ver qué respuestas obtengo.

Si tengo una clase definida como:

```
class A {
protected:
    ~A(){ }
};
```

Entonces puedo asignar dinámicamente el individuo así como el arreglo de objetos como:

```
A* ptr1 = new A;
A* ptr2 = new A[10];
```

Sin embargo, cuando defino el constructor para esta clase:

```
class A {
public:
    A(){}
protected:
    ~A(){ }
};
```

Entonces puedo crear objetos individuales con:

```
A* ptr = new A;
```

Pero cuando intento asignar dinámicamente la matriz de objeto con:

```
A* ptr = new A[10];
```

El compilador (gcc-5.1 and Visual Studio 2015) se queja de que el destructor `A::~A()` es inacesible.

Puede alguien explicar...

1. ¿Por qué se define y no define la diferencia de comportamiento con el constructor?
2. Cuando se define el constructor por qué se me permite crear un objeto individual y no una matriz de objetos.

Comment: Creo que deberías haber mencionado que se trata de una pregunta del usuario Dinesh Maurya de Stackoverflow (Dynamic allocation of class array with protected destructor) y no tuya. No conozco las reglas del sitio, pero en otros ámbitos podría llamarse plagio.

Comment: ¿Por qué has traducido la pregunta original sin mencionar su origen? Fue una mera actitud chupóptera o fue un descuido?

Comment: La verdad fue un descuido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problema.

Es normal que el compilador de queje de que el destructor no es accesible porque... el destructor no es accesible. Tanto si el objeto tiene constructor como si carece del mismo el destructor puede ser requerido para destruir objetos.

#### ¿Cuándo falla?

Veamos todos los ejemplos en que tenemos fallos:

```
class SinConstructor {
    ~SinConstructor() {} // Destructor privado
};

class ConConstructor {
    ~ConConstructor() {} // Destructor privado
public:
    ConConstructor() {}
};
```

Estas dos clases tienen destructor privado, y una de ellas constructor definido por el usuario los usos serían:

```
int main()
{
    SinConstructor sc; // Error: destructor inaccesible.
    ConConstructor cc; // Error: destructor inaccesible.

    // Sin problemas: constructor por defecto accesible. No usa el destructor.
    SinConstructor *psc = new SinConstructor;
    // Sin problemas: constructor definido por el usuario accesible. No usa el destructor.
    ConConstructor *pcc = new ConConstructor;

    // Sin problemas: constructor por defecto accesible. No usa el destructor.
    SinConstructor *asc = new SinConstructor[42];
    // Error: destructor inaccesible.
    ConConstructor *acc = new ConConstructor[42];

    delete *psc; // Error: destructor inaccesible.
    delete *pcc; // Error: destructor inaccesible.

    delete [] asc; // Error: destructor inaccesible.
    delete [] pcc; // Error: destructor inaccesible.

    return 0; // Aqui finaliza el ciclo de vida de sc y cc
}
```

El código fallará cuando el compilador necesite acceder al código del destructor:

1. Las instancias `sc` y `cc` son variables automáticas y su ciclo de vida finaliza al salir de la función `main`, ahí se llamaría automáticamente su destructor el cuál, al no ser accesible: provoca fallo de compilación.
2. Las instancias apuntadas por `psc` y `pcc` son variables dinámicas y su ciclo de vida finaliza al llamar al operador `delete`, es en ese punto en que el compilador detecta el error.
3. A grandes rasgos los arreglos apuntados por `asc` y `acc`:

   - `asc` se comporta como el caso 2.
   - `acc` se comporta como el caso 1.

#### Explicación.

C++ trata de manera diferenciada ciertas funciones especiales de los objetos, estas funciones son:

- Constructor.
- Destructor.
- Operador de asignación-copia.
- Constructor de movimiento (C++11 o superior).
- Operador de asignación-movimiento (C++11 o superior).

El trato especial que se da a estas funciones es que si el usuario no los provee, el compilador las generará automáticamente **si son necesarias**, de la misma manera que puede decidir no compilar-usar funciones si no son usadas. Así que ¿cuándo es usado el destructor? Según el [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 12.4 Destructores
>
> ...
>
> 11. Un destructor es invocado implícitamente
>
>     - (11.1) para los objetos de duración de almacenamiento estática al fianlizar el programa.
>     - (11.2) para los objetos de duración de almacenamiento de hilo al finalizar el hilo.
>     - (11.3) para los objetos de duración almacenamiento automática cuando el bloque en que fueron creados finaliza.
>     - (11.4) para los objetos temporales cuando su ciclo de vida finaliza.
>
> En cada caso, el contexto de invocación es el contexto de construcción del objeto. El destructor es también invocado implícitamente mediante el uso de una *expresión-delete* para objetos construidos por una *expresión-new*; el contexto de invocación es la *expresión-delete* [*Nota:* Un arreglo de tipo objeto contiene múltiples sub-objetos para cada uno de los cuales el destructor es invocado. *-fin de la nota*] El destructor también puede ser invocado explícitamente. **Un destructor es *potencialmente invocado* si es invocado o como se especifica en 5.3.4** y 12.6.2. **El programa está mal formado si el destructor que es potencialmente invocado está borrado o no es accesible desde el contexto de la invocación**.

La parte citada en 12.4.11 (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 5.3.4 New
>
> ...
>
> 8. Una *expresión-new* podrá obtener almacenamiento para el objeto llamando a una función de alojamiento. **Si la *expresión-new* finaliza lanzando una excepción, liberará el almacenamiento llamando a la función de des-alojamiento.** [...]

En el caso de `SinConstructor`, el constructor es generado automáticamente por el compilador y es considerado [trivial](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Constructor_predeterminado_trivial), para objetos triviales no se invoca el destructor del objeto si no que se llama a la función de des-alojamiento.

En el caso de `ConConstructor`, al disponer de un constructor definido por el usuario (aún estando vacío) el objeto no puede considerarse trivial y el destructor será potencialmente requerido, todo destructor no accesible y potencialmente requerido hace que el código esté mal formado.

Comment: Magnífica explicación, con los puntos concretos del estandar detallados. Gran trabajo. +1

Answer (score 3):

Esta pregunta está disponible en [*Dynamic allocation of class array with protected destructor*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779374/dynamic-allocation-of-class-array-with-protected-destructor).
Esto **es** una traducción *libre y ampliada* de la respuesta aceptada de dicha pregunta.

1. En el primer caso, el compilador crea un *constructor por defecto*. Es un constructor vacío, que no hace absolutamente nada. Pero, como está creado por el compilador, sabe que dicho constructor **no puede fallar**. **No puede lanzar excepciones**.
2. En el segundo caso, tú creas el constructor. El hecho de que esté igualmente vacío **no influye**; el compilador solo sabe que no es el que él crea por defecto, y, por lo tanto, **sí puede fallar**. **Sí puede lanzar excepciones**.

Hagamos un inciso para explicar *muy por encima* el funcionamiento de las excepciones. Un poco de código:

```
void func( int x ) {
  char* pleak = new char[1024]; // Se pierde.
  std::string str( "hello world" ); // Se libera.

  if( x ) throw std::runtime_error( "boom" );

  delete[] pleak; // Solo llegamos aquí si x == 0.
}

int main( ) {
  try {
    func( 10 );
  }
  catch ( const std::exception& e ) {
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

En este ejemplo, `main( )` devolverá `1`; `delete[] pleak` nunca será llamado, por lo que esos `1024` *bytes* **nunca serán liberados** y se perderán por los siglos de los siglos (al perderse el puntero que *los apunta*).

Sin embargo, la memoria utilizada *internamente* por `str` **sí se libera**. Esto se realiza mediante un procedimiento llamado *desbobinado de pila*, mediante el cual *se llama a los destructores de las instancias creadas en el ámbito en el que se lanzó la excepción*. En este ejemplo, la única instancia es `str`, aunque podrían existir más, y el proceso sería el mismo.

Ahora, el caso concreto de los *arrays* de instancias.

Cuando tú haces `A *tmp = new A[10];`, en realidad estás llamando *consecutivamente* a los constructores de las 10 instancias que has creado. Gráficamente, sería algo así:

```
[new A( )], [new A( )], [new A( )], [new A( )], [new A( )], ...
```

Ahora, si se produjera una excepción en el 3º `new A( )`, ... ¿qué pasaría ?

Exacto. Que el compilador generaría código para llamar a los destructores del los elementos 2º y 1º, **pero no al que falló**.

Ahora, queda claro el motivo del error que indicas en la pregunta. En el primer caso, como el constructor **no puede lanzar excepciones**, no se necesita un *destructor* al que llamar.

En el segundo caso, el constructor **sí puede lanzar excepciones**; es necesario, pues, un destructor al que llamar. Como lo has declarado `protected`, **no está disponible** desde fuera de la propia clase, y el compilador *se queja*.

¿Por qué **no hay error** al crear una sola instancia? Pues **porque no es necesario**. En caso de excepción, sólo se llaman a los destructores de los objetos **que hayan sido correctamente construidos**. Si solo creas una instancia (y no un *array*), tan sólo hay **1** objeto. Si se construye correctamente, no pasa nada. Si falla el constructor, **no hay** más instancias correctas a las que llamar, así que no se necesita el destructor.

Siguiendo esta explicación, en C++11, si declararas el constructor como `noexcept`, informarías al compilador de que **no lanzarás excepciones**, con lo que no se tendría que generar el error. No obstante, con mi versión de g++ (6.2.0), se sigue indicando el error, lo que hace sospechar de un *bug* en dicho compilador.

El caso de `clang 3.8.1` es aun peor: muestra el error en **ambos** casos, con *constructor por defecto* y con *constructor explícito*.

Comment: La respuesta que traduces no se encuentra en la dirección que indicas ([StackOverflow.com][1]) ¿Puede ser que el autor original de la respuesta la haya eliminado por considerarla errónea? Qué lástima que no mencionas al autor para poder verificarlo. 
De todos modos, convendría que revises esta respuesta, o que imites al autor y corrijas el error.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779374/dynamic-allocation-of-class-array-with-protected-destructor

Comment: No es una traducción *literal* de ninguna de ellas, sino un *desarrollo* de lo explicado allí, mas algunos detalles extra. Consideré *correcto* indicar esas fuentes. No se porqué dices que es errónea. Explico el motivo, y el **porqué** de ese motivo. ¿ Que aspecto de la respuesta es incorrecto ?

Comment: Vale, ya se lo que ha pasado. La respuesta se hizo *a trozos*, sufriendo **varias ediciones** antes de publicarla. El texto en el que indiqué las fuentes fue lo primero que escribí, y nunca lo modifiqué. Comenzó siendo simple, y se fue ampliando, hasta que al final, efectivamente, tiene poco que ver con la referencia que indico. No obstante, por ahí empezó todo.

Comment: El motivo y su por qué, `El caso de clang 3.8.1 es aun peor: muestra el error en ambos casos, con constructor por defecto y con constructor explícito.` por ejemplo, es, de acuerdo con el estándar. justamente el comportamiento correcto.

Comment: @asdasdasd no domino tanto el inglés como para *enfrentarme* al estandar, por lo que no puedo rebatir tu motivo. Sin embargo, la primera línea de la respuesta aceptada en la pregunta referida es `Rejecting an array-new with a protected destructor is correct`, y mas abajo hace referencia a las excepciones en los arrays de objetos, y el comportamiento del compilador en esos casos. Siéntete libre de aportar tu respuesta y aclarar mis dudas, y con gusto de haré +1.

Comment: `no domino tanto el inglés como para enfrentarme al estandar, por lo que no puedo rebatir tu motivo` Quizá sólo convenga empezar por entenderlo y después, si te pluguiere, rebatirlo. Por otro lado, yo no daría una respuesta hasta que @Mateo Guzmán no aclarase si la falta de mención al autor de la pregunta se trató de un error involuntario.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52229/discussion-between-asdasdasd-and-trauma).